# Is it possible to make two grayscale images stastistically equivalent?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have 2 grayscale images say G1 and G2 . I also have the statistics (min ,max ,mean and Standard Deviation). I would like to change G2 such that the statistics of G2 (min ,max,mean and SD)match G1. I have tried arithmetic scaling and got the min and max values of both G1 and G2 to match but mean and SD are still different. I have also tried Histogram fitting of G2 in G1 but that did not do what i wanted either. I am using a software called SPIDER this a question applicable to image-processing which can be performed using different software packages(OpenCV MATLABetc) .Any ideas and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Anything is possible.  What have you tried already?  Can you show your work-in-progress code?  Do you have a more specific programming question?

Comment: The software I mentioned (SPIDER) performs the operation and transforms the image. I am looking for the approach /method rather than for code. I have mentioned what I have tried(i.e Histogram fitting, arithmetic scaling)

Comment: Histogram matching is going to be closest to what you want to do, but I don't think there's a way to make two arbitrary grayscale images statistically identical. Consider one image with an even distribution of grayscale values in the range `0..255` and another with all pixel values equal to `3`. Making the mean identical is easy, but the other statistics will never be the same.

Comment: What would someone want to do that? what would you gain by doing so? this might help in answering!

Comment: @beaker - That should be an answer.

Comment: @Samer making the two images equivalent greatly simplifies my further processing steps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to apply histogram equalization to both images (`histeq` in MATLAB). If you do not want to change both images, then you can do [histogram matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_matching), but that's a bit more complicated.

Comment: Agree.  Seems that histogram matching is the best approach to try and match the global statistics of the image as best as possible with another.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a mapping of input to output based on a simple curve. Start with the values that don't have any dependencies, min and max - those will set the ends of the curve. Now map the mean values to create a single point in the middle of the curve. To modify the standard deviation, you change the shape of the curve between the mean and the endpoints - a curve that is flatter in the middle will give less deviation, and a curve that is flatter towards the ends but steeper in the middle will magnify it.

Edit: I haven't given this enough thought yet, changing the shape of the curve will also change the mean. But I think it can be worked into something usable.

Comment: I would go this way too... although I didn't see any constraint preventing simply replacing the second image with the first ;-)

Comment: There is a constraint on replacing the second image with the first .I am using another software in  the further image processing steps. If i am successful in somehow making the two images equivalent it basically simplifies my problem greatly. Thank you @Mark Ransom I shall work on your sggestons

Answer (score 0):

I marked the histogram equalization answer as right because it gave me the best results however  I was unable to make the 2 images exactly statistically equivalent as such